# Passing custom c++ type as QML function parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Im trying to create and pass a custom class instance to a Q_INVOKABLE function with the respective parameter.
I tried to make an example to point out what im trying to do. So basically i have a class Foo and another class Bar with a function that takes Foo as a parameter. I want to call this function in QML but i don't know how to instantiate Foo to pass it as the parameter for that function.

**EDIT - More information about the main goal:**

The real goal is to have a subclassed QAbstractItemModel that has a list of a custom class objects. That list will then be represented using the models data() function. The model should be represented some how as a view in QML. Also i want to populate the model at runtime. So the model class should have a function that takes a custom class instance and appends it to the internal list. So my approach was to create and pass the custom class instance within qml. I haven't found any example to do that kind of taks.
Here is what i've got:

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName)
public:
    Foo(QString fooName, QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent){
        name = fooName;
    }          
    QString getName() const {
        return name;
    }
    void setName(const QString &value){
        name = value;
    }    
private:
    QString name;
};
```

**Bar.h**

```
class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Bar(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent){}

    Q_INVOKABLE void addFoo(const Foo &foo){
        fooList.append(foo);
    } 
private:
    QList<Foo> fooList;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<Foo>("Test", 1, 0, "Foo");
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("bar", new Bar());    
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import Test 1.0

Window {    
    Button {
        id: addFoo
        text: "Add new Foo to Bar"
        onClicked: {
            bar.addFoo(????)
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, set context properties BEFORE loading QML. Context properties *must* be set *before* loading QML that references the context properties. It still *can* work but you can incur in strange bugs due to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either make `Foo` instantiable, by giving it a constructor that can be called without arguments, and then use the approach suggested by CMLDMR or you add a "factory" function that can create instances.

In the latter case you either need to work with `Foo*` as the return value of the factory function and the argument of `addFoo()` or you change `Foo` to be a value class with the `Q_GADGET` macro for properties instead of deriving from `QObject`

Given that you have no signals in `Foo` I would recommend the latter.

Roughly like this:

```
class Foo
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(...)

// ....
};


class Bar : public QObject
{
// ...

    Q_INVOKABLE Foo createFoo(const QString &name);
    Q_INVOKABLE void addFoo(const Foo &foo);
};
```

Edit: it also requires

```
qRegisterMetaType<Foo>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the following error as i change the code as u mentioned: "Error: Unknown method return type: Foo". What did i miss?

Comment: Is this a compiler error or from the QML environment?

Comment: It comes from the qml environment as I call the createFoo function.

Comment: Ah, it also needs `qRegisterMetaType()` for `Foo`. will ammend the answer

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks! Is there a good resource that covers that topic in detail? I would like to see a good example of how to integrate c++ in QML.

Comment: @Matthias I don't think there is one single super example, unfortunately, but the info spread out over the documentation. One issue is that there are a lot of different aspects of QML/C++ integration and even real projects often only need specific sub sets.

Comment: @Matthias just to emphasis the last point about the wide range of topics: it is enough material to last for a 3 day training course here at KDAB: https://www.kdab.com/software-services/scheduled-training/programming-with-qt/advanced-qml-training/

Answer (score 1):

you should create a object by **Foo** before passing object in QML.
Source: [Qt5 C++ GUI Programming Cookbook. Lee Zhi Eng](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/Application%20Development/9781783280278/1/ch01lvl1sec16/Exposing+QML+object+pointer+to+C++), page:37

```
import Test 1.0

Window {
    Foo {
    id: Foo_object
    }    
    Button {
        id: addFoo
        text: "Add new Foo to Bar"
        onClicked: {
            bar.addFoo(Foo_object)
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: But i want to dynamically create Foo objects not just a predefined amount. Or can i always use the same? And if i do like u said i get following error: "Error: Unknown method parameter type: Foo"

Comment: @Matthias It's really difficult to help since it is not clear the lifetime you want to give to these objects. "Can I always use the same" has only an answer: "it really depends on what you want to achieve". But that's something we can not easily infer here. Generally speaking, you can generate instances dynamically by following the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) or maybe by using an [`Instantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html).